# Ping multiple IP's without exiting from SSH using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ping

I have list of IP's which has to be pinged each other. Once I SSH to IP-1, i should ping all IP's in a loop before I come out of the loop.

I have tried the below..

```
for name in "${ip[@]}";
do
 status=$(ssh -n -o LogLevel=QUIET -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
  ubuntu@$node ping -W 2 -q -c 5 $name")
  if [ "$?" -eq "2" ]; then
   echo -e "$(tput setab 7) $(tput setaf 1)$(date) $i unable to ping $name 
   $(tput sgr0)"
 fi
done
```

This code is working. However every time it requires to do SSH, which is having a performance impact as i'm having more than 100 IP's in the list.

Can I get any help on this?

Comment: I'm looking for looping inside ssh in the above mentioned code or anything similar to that.

Comment: How I'd do it is use the loop to create a shell script which I then copy to the remote server and run there. To copy and run, I'd do something like `ssh ... ubuntu@$node "cat > /tmp/pinger && sh /tmp/pinger ; rm /tmp/pinger" < localversionpinger`

Comment: what do you mean by ‘performance impact’? how long do you think it should take if you ping 100 hosts 5 times each, single-threaded ?

Answer (score 2):

You could just make this list part of the command that you run on your target host, something like this:

```
ips=( "10.0.0.1" "10.0.0.2")
ssh serverName 'for i in '${ips[@]}'; do ping ${i} -c1; done'
```

Note the breaking single-quote to pass the array.

Edit:

Just to have it mentioned here: the tool "fping" is quite right for the job. It would give you just the list you asked for:

```
ips=( "10.0.0.1" "10.0.0.2")
ssh serverName 'fping -a '${ips[@]}' 2>/dev/null'
```

Cupcake is right about the possible problems that arise when you passing the list as suggested having entries containing whitespaces. In this special case, however, there are no whitespaces to be expected.

This should give you the List of IPs without fping

```
ips=( "10.0.0.1" "10.0.0.2")
ssh serverName 'for host in '${ips[@]}'; do if ping -c1 -w1 ${host} >/dev/null 2>&1; then echo ${host};fi;done'
```

Comment: This should work, for this case, but quoting commands for use with ssh is rather complicated. `abc=("a b c","d e f"); ssh servername 'for i in '${abc[@]}'; do touch "$i"; done'` won't work as neatly.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian and Cupcake. In the approach shared, i'm not able judge whether it is working or not. Sorry that i'm still learning the ways of having a single line command. I tried  status=$(ssh -n -o LogLevel=QUIET -t -t -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@$node 'for name in '${containerName[@]}';do; echo -e \"Pingning to $name\"; ping -W 2 -q -c 5 \"$name\";if [ \"$?\" -eq \"2\" ]; then; echo -e \"$(tput setab 7) $(tput setaf 1)$(date) $i unable to ping $name $(tput sgr0)\";fi; done'") " I need to parse the ping result and say which IP i was not able to ping.